# How to start the build from the middle of a pipeline based on git commit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following pipeline (Basically, Build_BASE triggers in parallel 3 downstream builds):

```
             -> BUILD1
Build_BASE   -> BUILD2
             -> BULID3
```

If someone does a git commit to Build_Base it will start the entire pipeline.

But if someone does a commit to BUILD1 or 2 or 3, I want the build to start at that point and NOT build Build_Base.  Is this possible?

Here is a stripped down version of my pipeline (I didn't add git polling to this yet)

```
stage('Base_AMI') {
  node('eod-us-west-2_shared') {
    stage('Build') {
      deleteDir()
      git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '2df157d3-f9c3-4005-91d0-b3052764474f', url: 'git@github.com:myrepo/base_ami.git'
      sh "bash do_build.sh"
    }
  }
}

stage("DOWNSTREAM_BUILDS"){
  parallel (
    "BUILD1" : {
       node('eod-us-west-2_shared') {
         wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
             sh 'echo ${BUILD_USER}'
             deleteDir()
             git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '2df157d3-f9c3-4005-91d0-b3052764474f', url: 'git@github.com:myrepo/build1.git'
             sh "bash do_build.sh"
         }
      }
    },
    "BUILD2" : {
       node('eod-us-west-2_shared') {
             deleteDir()
             git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '2df157d3-f9c3-4005-91d0-b3052764474f', url: 'git@github.com:myrepo/build2.git'
             sh "bash /private/myrepo/git_clone_repo.sh"
             sh "bash do_build.sh"
         }
     },
    "BUILD3" : {
       node('eod-us-west-2_shared') {
             deleteDir()
             git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '2df157d3-f9c3-4005-91d0-b3052764474f', url: 'git@github.com:myrepo/build3.git'
             sh "bash do_build.sh"
         }
     }
  )
}
```

Comment: That's 1 repository in total, or 4?

Comment: 4 unique git repositories.  thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what should happen is that each of your git repositories should have it's on pipeline with Jenkinsfile of it's own.

Then in you upstream job you would just do:

```
stage("DOWNSTREAM_BUILDS"){
  parallel (
    // job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("job1") },
    { build("job2") },
    { build("job3") }
  )
}
```

The whole trick is your pipelines configuration - each should be polling just it's own git repository.